# Where is the Java Swing counterpart of "GetMessage()" loop?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I did some Win32 GUI programming several years ago. Now I am using Java Swing.

Just out of curiosity, where is the Swing counterpart of Win32 message loop logic? In Win32, it is achieved with the API [GetMessage()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I guess it must have been wrapped deeply somewhere.

Comment: It's buried inside the native code, which is wrapped by `Toolkit` and the `EventQueue`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks for the hint. Sometimes I just can't help think about under-the-hood.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Overview

The following diagram broadly illustrates how Swing/AWT works on the Windows platform:

```
       Our Listeners
             ▲
             │ (Events dispatched to our code by EDT)
 ╭ ◀─────────┴───────────╮
 │ Event Dispatch Thread │
 ╰───────────▲─────────▶ ╯
             │ (Events pulled from the queue by EDT)
             │
        Event Queue
             ▲
             │ (Events posted to the queue by WToolkit)
 ╭ ◀─────────┴───────────╮
 │    WToolkit Thread    │
 ╰───────────▲─────────▶ ╯
             │ (Messages pulled by WToolkit via PeekMessage)
             │
        Windows API
```

This architecture is almost entirely hidden from us by the event-driven abstraction. We only interact with the top-most end when events are triggered (`actionPerformed`, `paintComponent`, etc.) and by occasionally posting events ourselves (`invokeLater`, `repaint`, etc.).

Official documentation on the subject tends to be very general so I'm going to use (very paraphrased) excerpts from the source code.

#### Event Dispatch Thread

The EDT is the Swing event processing thread and [all Swing programs run primarily on this thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). For the most part, this is just the AWT system and it's located in [`java.awt.EventDispatchThread`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/awt/EventDispatchThread.java).

The event dispatching system is pretty dispersed, so I'll walk through a specific example supposing a `JButton` has been clicked.

To begin figuring out what's going on, we might look at a stack trace.

```java
class ClickStack {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                JButton button = new JButton("Click for stack trace");

                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        new Error().printStackTrace(System.out);
                    }
                });

                frame.add(button);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This program gets us a call stack like the following:

```java
at sscce.ClickStack$1$1.actionPerformed
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed
...
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent
...
at java.awt.Component.processEvent
...
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl
...
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl
...
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter
...
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run
```

If we take a look at the [`EventDispatchThread.run`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/awt/EventDispatchThread.java#l80) method, we see:

```java
public void run() {
    try {
        pumpEvents(...);
    } finally {
        ...
    }
}
```

[`EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/awt/EventDispatchThread.java#l92) takes us to [`EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/awt/EventDispatchThread.java#l112) which contains the outer loop logic:

```java
void pumpEventsForFilter(...) {
    ...
    while(doDispatch && ...) {
        pumpOneEventForFilters(...);
    }
    ...
}
```

An event is then pulled off the queue and sent off for dispatch in [`EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/awt/EventDispatchThread.java#l156):

```java
void pumpOneEventForFilters(...) {
    AWTEvent event = null;
    ...
    try {
        ...
        EventQueue eq = getEventQueue();
        ...
        event = eq.getNextEvent();
        ...
        eq.dispatchEvent(event);
        ...
    } catch(...) {
        ...
    } ...
}
```

[`java.awt.EventQueue`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/awt/EventQueue.java) contains logic where the type of event is narrowed and the event is further dispatched. [`EventQueue.dispatchEvent`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/awt/EventQueue.java#l689) calls [`EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/awt/EventQueue.java#l736) where we see the following decision structure:

```java
if (event instanceof ActiveEvent) {
    ...
    ((ActiveEvent)event).dispatch();
} else if (src instanceof Component) {
    ((Component)src).dispatchEvent(event);
    ...
} else if (src instanceof MenuComponent) {
    ((MenuComponent)src).dispatchEvent(event);
} else if (src instanceof TrayIcon) {
    ((TrayIcon)src).dispatchEvent(event);
} else if (src instanceof AWTAutoShutdown) {
    ...
    dispatchThread.stopDispatching();
} else {
    ...
}
```

Most events we are familiar with go through the `Component` path.

[`Component.dispatchEvent`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/awt/Component.java#l4698) calls [`Component.dispatchEventImpl`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/awt/Component.java#l4708) which, for most listener-type events, calls [`Component.processEvent`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/awt/Component.java#l6261) where the event is narrowed down and forwarded again:

```java
/**
 * Processes events occurring on this component. By default this
 * method calls the appropriate process<event type>Event
 * method for the given class of event.
 * ...
 */
protected void processEvent(AWTEvent e) {
    if (e instanceof FocusEvent) {
        processFocusEvent((FocusEvent)e);
    } else if (e instanceof MouseEvent) {
        switch(e.getID()) {
          case MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED:
          case MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED:
          case MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED:
          case MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED:
          case MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED:
              processMouseEvent((MouseEvent)e);
              break;
          case ...:
              ...
        }
    } else if (e instanceof KeyEvent) {
        processKeyEvent((KeyEvent)e);
    } else if (e instanceof ComponentEvent) {
        processComponentEvent((ComponentEvent)e);
    } else if (...) {
        ...
    } ...
}
```

For a `JButton` click, we're following a `MouseEvent`.

These low level events ultimately have a single handler internal to the `Component`. So for example, we might have a look at [`javax.swing.plaf.BasicButtonListener`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicButtonListener.java) which implements a number of listener interfaces.

`BasicButtonListener` uses the mouse events to change the pressed state of the button model. Finally, the button model determines if it's been clicked in [`DefaultButtonModel.setPressed`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/javax/swing/DefaultButtonModel.java#l237), fires an `ActionEvent` and our listener's `actionPerformed` gets called.

#### Native Messaging

How the actual native window is implemented is of course platform-specific but I can go through the Windows platform a bit since it's what you asked about. You'll find the Windows platform stuff in the following directories:

- Java: [`src/windows/classes/sun/awt/windows`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/classes/sun/awt/windows/)
- Native: [`src/windows/native/sun/windows`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/native/sun/windows/)

The Windows implementation of `java.awt.Toolkit`, which is [`sun.awt.windows.WToolkit`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/classes/sun/awt/windows/WToolkit.java), starts a separate thread for the actual message loop. [`WToolkit.run`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/classes/sun/awt/windows/WToolkit.java#l292) calls a JNI method `eventLoop`. [A comment in the source file](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/classes/sun/awt/windows/WToolkit.java#l310) explains that:

```cpp
/*
 * eventLoop() begins the native message pump which retrieves and processes
 * native events.
 * ...
```

This leads us to the C++ `AwtToolkit` class, located in [`awt_Toolkit.h`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/native/sun/windows/awt_Toolkit.h) and [`awt_Toolkit.cpp`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/native/sun/windows/awt_Toolkit.cpp) (other classes follow the same file name convention).

The [native implementation of `eventLoop`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/native/sun/windows/awt_Toolkit.cpp#l2204) calls [`AwtToolkit::MessageLoop`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/native/sun/windows/awt_Toolkit.cpp#l1217):

```cpp
AwtToolkit::GetInstance().MessageLoop(AwtToolkit::PrimaryIdleFunc,
                                      AwtToolkit::CommonPeekMessageFunc);
```

([`AwtToolkit::CommonPeekMessageFunc`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/native/sun/windows/awt_Toolkit.cpp#l1384) calls [`PeekMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-peekmessagea), which is the non-blocking alter-ego of [`GetMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage).)

This is where the outer loop is located:

```cpp
UINT
AwtToolkit::MessageLoop(IDLEPROC lpIdleFunc,
                        PEEKMESSAGEPROC lpPeekMessageFunc)
{
    ...

    m_messageLoopResult = 0;
    while (!m_breakMessageLoop) {

        (*lpIdleFunc)();

        PumpWaitingMessages(lpPeekMessageFunc); /* pumps waiting messages */
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

[`AwtToolkit::PumpWaitingMessages`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/native/sun/windows/awt_Toolkit.cpp#l1317) actually has a familiar-looking message loop, which calls [`TranslateMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-translatemessage) and [`DispatchMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dispatchmessage):

```cpp
/*
 * Called by the message loop to pump the message queue when there are
 * messages waiting. Can also be called anywhere to pump messages.
 */
BOOL AwtToolkit::PumpWaitingMessages(PEEKMESSAGEPROC lpPeekMessageFunc)
{
    MSG  msg;
    BOOL foundOne = FALSE;
    ...

    while (!m_breakMessageLoop && (*lpPeekMessageFunc)(msg)) {
        foundOne = TRUE;
        ProcessMsg(msg); // calls TranslateMessage & DispatchMessage (below)
    }
    return foundOne;
}

void AwtToolkit::ProcessMsg(MSG& msg)
{
    if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) {
        ...
    }
    else if (msg.message != WM_NULL) {
        ...

        ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
        ::DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

(And recall that `DispatchMessage` calls the [`WindowProc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) callback.)

The native window is wrapped by a C++ object which has platform-specific stuff, as well as a loose parallel of some of the API we have in Java code.

There seem to be a couple of `WindowProc` functions. One is just used internally by the toolkit, [`AwtToolkit::WndProc`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/native/sun/windows/awt_Toolkit.cpp#l688), along with [an empty window](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/native/sun/windows/awt_Toolkit.cpp#l346).

The `WindowProc` function we're actually interested in is [`AwtComponent::WndProc`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/native/sun/windows/awt_Component.cpp#l380). `WndProc` calls a virtual function called [`AwtComponent::WindowProc`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/native/sun/windows/awt_Component.cpp#l1308). Some subclasses override `WindowProc` (e.g. [`AwtFrame::WindowProc`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/native/sun/windows/awt_Frame.cpp#l408)), but a majority of messages are handled by `AwtComponent::WindowProc`. For example, it contains the following switch case:

```cpp
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
    mr = WmMouseDown(static_cast<UINT>(wParam), myPos.x, myPos.y,
                     LEFT_BUTTON);
    break;
```

[`AwtComponent::WmMouseDown`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/native/sun/windows/awt_Component.cpp#l2311) begins a series of calls that posts a `java.awt.MouseEvent` to the `EventQueue` in Java:

```cpp
SendMouseEvent(java_awt_event_MouseEvent_MOUSE_PRESSED, now, x, y,
               GetJavaModifiers(), clickCount, JNI_FALSE,
               GetButton(button), &msg);
```

After the event is posted, we are ultimately led back to the top where the event is seen on the EDT.

Comment: @Radiodef Does the message pumping loop in AwtToolkit::PumpWaitingMessages keeps running when java VM is started and running?

Comment: @chunsj It's been awhile since I've looked at this, but I think the event queue starts up whenever the first Swing/AWT call is made (like `invokeLater` or other calls) and ends whenever the VM shuts down. If you never use Swing/AWT, the event queue never starts.

Comment: @Radiodef Thank you, this helps me solve my own weird problem in my JNI module greatly. You're my hero :-)