# Call a method in a class that implements runnable

Tags: java, swing

Trying to create a maze generator, to get the `repaint()` to work I had to add the `swingUtilities.invokeLater` in main, and make the graphics class implement Runnable with `new Thread(this).start();` in the constructor.

However, I want the maze to regenerate on a button click, which is in the button class.

Simply calling the method from another class seems to work as `println` still prints but nothing is repainted onto the panel, resizing the window also doesn't change anything.

I've tried creating a new thread using the below code but the same thing happens?

```
MazeArea ma = new MazeArea();

Thread t = new Thread(ma);

t.start();
```

Main Class

```
public class MainGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // executes code
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Graphics Class

```
public class MazeArea extends JComponent implements Runnable {
    public MazeArea() {
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void run() {
        generateMaze();
        clear();
    }

    synchronized protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawMaze(g);
    }
}
```

Button Class

```
public class VariableDetails extends JPanel {
    public VariableDetails() {
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {                   
                MazeArea ma = new MazeArea();

                Thread t = new Thread(ma);

                t.start();
            }
        });
    }
```

How would I just rerun a thread?

Comment: *How would I just rerun a thread?* You would not.

Comment: It doesn't look to me like there's any reason to use threads here, unless generating the maze takes a really long time. If you need a background task sometimes, use [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), or if you want to do animation, use a [Swing `Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: @Radiodef it doesn't take a really long time, it's very quick but if I don't have the `Runnable` then the repaint doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? If you have some kind of an infinite loop that does animation and calls `repaint()`, then you should use a timer (like I already suggested). Possibly see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29837148/2891664) for an explanation. If you want more specific help, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54374266/edit) to add a [mcve] which reproduces the problem you're having.