# How to get multiple bullets to fire? (Repeated action during key-press)

Tags: java

I am making a game but I can only get one bullet to fire, how can I get multiple bullets to fire when the space bar is pressed?

There is a main class. This contains the the size of the frame for the space game.

This is the shooter class. Here I draw the bullet and spaceship and set the left and right controls for the movement of the spaceship.

```
    boolean right, left; 
    int bulletX;
    int rectX = 320;
    int rectY = 435;
    int bulletY;
    Rectangle bullet;
    boolean space, fire;
    boolean shot;

    public ShooterGame() {
        addKeyListener(this);
        this.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        this.setFocusable(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 700, 500);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 700, 500);

        graphics.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        graphics.drawRect(rectX, rectY, 50, 30);
        graphics.fillRect(rectX, rectY, 50, 30);

        if (shot) {
            graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
            graphics.fillRect(bullet.x, bullet.y, bullet.width, bullet.height);
        }
        repaint();
    }

    


    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                moveToRight();
        }

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                moveToLeft();
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            if (bullet == null) {
                fire = true;
                if (fire) {
                    bulletX = rectX;
                    bulletY = rectY;
                    bullet = new Rectangle(bulletX + 25, bulletY, 3, 5);
                    shot = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

   


    public void shootBullet() {
        if (shot) {
            bullet.y--;
            System.out.println("shot fired");
        }
```

Comment: keyPressed does just that: when you PRESS the key, not WHILE you press the key. You can start a loop at keyPressed, and stop that loop at keyReleased.

Comment: Watch out -- entering a loop at KeyPressed doesn't solve the problem, and in fact would create some interesting behavior in this program since it would block the thread.

Comment: 1) never invoke repaint() from a painting method. 2) you need to invoke super.paintComponent(..) as the first statement in the paintComponent() method to make sure the background is cleared. 3) check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028090/get-width-and-height-of-jpanel-outside-of-the-class/54028681#54028681 for an example of animating multiple objects. How you add/remove object from the ArrayLiist is up to the requirements of your game.

Comment: Just as a side note, you should use `javax.swing.Timer` instead of using a `Thread`. Swing is supposed to be single-thread and your code isn't thread-safe right now, so you could have memory consistency errors. (There are times when you want to use a background thread but it's more complicated to get right.) See this answer for some examples of how to refactor to use a timer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29837148/2891664 You should also call `repaint` in your game loop instead of inside `paintComponent`.

Comment: Add a tag for what Java GUI framework you are using. (Swing, JavaFX, SWT, Vaadin, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code, your KeyPressed/KeyReleased logic is correct for firing multiple bullets -- you are setting a boolean `fireBullet` to true on `keyPressed` events and then to false on `keyReleased`.

However, it appears you can only have exactly one `Rectangle bullet` at any given time because you have only declared one. The bullet instance will always be overwritten during the `keyPressed` event (the relevant line `bullet = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);`).

In order to have more than one bullet on-screen at a time, you need to keep track of the bullets via a List, array, or other structure allowing multiple instances of `Rectangle`s representing `bullet`.

The refactor would look something like this:

- Change the `Rectangle bullet` to `List<Rectangle> bullets` (or an array, or a Set, etc)
- `shootBullet` should check to see if `fireBullet` is true. If it is, you should add a new bullet to the list
- `shootBullet` should also move every bullet in the list (currently it moves the single instance of bullet)

One other thing to note -- depending on how frequently the frame updates, you may *also* want to keep track of how many bullets can be fired per second (the suggested changes would allow one bullet to be created per frame update, which may be too many). You would then need to track the time (or number of frame updates) since the last bullet was fired prior to spawning another. That would also need to happen in `shootBullet`.

Comment: oh, and don't forget to delete bullets from the list once they get off the screen!

Comment: You might want to edit your question to include that comment. Also when the bullet hits something.